# Get the tcp port web site is served on

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, tcp

I need to get a tcp port of the specified web site on IIS 7 and IIS 6 using C#. I have a console application that knows the web site's name. It should find a port this web site is served on.

Comment: You need to provide some more information - do you mean listing all the websites that are on IIS and the ports they are on? Or do you mean looking at the http request and seeing what port it was requested on? If you tell us what you are trying to do, we can give a suitable answer.

Comment: I need to launch a console application with startup argument that specifies the web site name. That application should exit with exit-code that equals tcp port.

Answer (score 4):

you can get with servervariables
Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"]

Comment: I need code that works in a console application. Not in an ASP web page.

Comment: you can put this information in the web page server... if you can't scan every port, just put that info into app.config

Answer (score 2):

I think I can use System.DirectoryServices for IIS 6 and Microsoft.Web.Administration for IIS 7.

Answer (score 1):

OK.  I'm going to give you a different answer since you commented that my last answer was not the answer to your question.

Try adding a `global.asax` file to your asp.net application.  It will have functions to handle different events on the server.  For the `Application_Start` function, you can have some code to save the port number that the web site is running on in a file or database somewhere.

Then, the console application can access the same file or database to find the port number.

If that doesn't suit you, then perhaps a better question to ask on SO would be "How can I programmatically read the IIS settings for a web site at run time?"

Comment: See here for more useful info: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

Comment: Is you answer about ASP.NET web page?

Comment: oh, I see you're running a console program seperate from the web site.  For a minute, I thought you were launching the console program from the web site.

Answer (score 1):

By default IIS binds to port 80 (default http port) but I am sure the answer is not that simple.

Maybe you could have used the admin scripts in IIS 6.0, to iterate through the IIS objects to find the port number, but this assumes the script is physically running on the server.

The only other option is run scan of each 65535 port to see if  there a html listener using wget maybe.

Comment: Every normal AV kills the process that scans all ports.

Answer (score 1):

FOR IIS 7 ;-)

```
private bool checkPortIsOpen(string portNumer)
    {
        ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();

        int index = 0;
        bool isOpen = true;

        foreach (Site mySite in serverMgr.Sites)
        {
            foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement binding in mySite.GetCollection("bindings"))
            {
                string protocol = (string)binding["protocol"];
                string bindingInfo = (string)binding["bindingInformation"];

                if (protocol.StartsWith("http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    string[] parts = bindingInfo.Split(':');
                    if (parts.Length == 3)
                    {
                        string port = parts[1];
                        if(port.Equals(portNumer.ToString()))
                        {
                            isOpen = false;
                            webSite_portInUse = mySite.Name;
                        }

                    }
                }
                index++;

            }
        }
        return isOpen;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to figure this out myself today, and got the answer I wanted, so figured I'd post it into this old thread.

You can determine the port by reading the IIS Metabase, which in IIS6 and above is an xml document.

In IIS6 get the file systemroot\system32\inetserv\metabase.xml and look at the node

/configuration/MBProperty/IIsWebServer[@ServerComment=$websitename]/serverBindings

In IIS7 get  the file systemroot\system32\inetserv\config\applicationHost.config
(it is xml, despite the .config extension) and look at the node 
/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='$websitename']